# Detox on Bitrise not working on Android - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, detox, bitrise

I have a detox configuration for my react native project and it works & passes for both platforms when I do it locally. Recently I tried adding this to the Bitrise workflow and it seems that there are some problems with the Android emulator there. I am using avd-manager.

It goes like this:

```
steps:
- git-clone@4.0.18:
    outputs:
    ...
- nvm@1.2.2:
    inputs:
    - node_version: ''
    title: NVM
- yarn@0:
    inputs:
    - command: pre-e2e // runs => (brew tap wix/brew && brew install applesimutils && npm install -g detox-cli)
    title: pre-e2e
- yarn@0:
    inputs:
    - command: ''
    title: yarn
- install-missing-android-tools@2: // added this step afterwards hoping it'd help, but nothing changed.
    inputs:
    - gradlew_path: "$PROJECT_LOCATION_ANDROID/gradlew"
- avd-manager@1:
    inputs:
    - api_level: '27'
- yarn@0:
    inputs:
    - command: e2e:build // runs => (detox build -c android.emu.release)
    title: Build Android
- yarn@0:
    inputs:
    - command: e2e:test // runs => (detox test -l verbose --forceExit -c android.emu.release)
    title: Test Android
```

As I said earlier, it runs just fine locally and I get the correct output. On bitrise I receive the following output (trimmed):

```
...
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #26] List of devices attached emulator-5554 device

detox[9851] DEBUG: [FreeDeviceFinder.js/DEVICE_LOOKUP] Found a matching & free device emulator-5554
detox[9851] DEBUG: [EmulatorDeviceAllocator.js/ALLOCATE_DEVICE] Settled on emulator-5554
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #27] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop dev.bootcomplete"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #28] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #29] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "settings put global animator_duration_scale 0"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #30] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "settings put global window_animation_scale 0"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #31] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "settings put global transition_animation_scale 0"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #32] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "dumpsys power | grep \"^[ ]*m[UW].*=\""
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #33] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.0/aapt" dump badging "/Users/vagrant/git/android/app/build/outputs/apk/example/release/example-release.apk" | grep -e "package: name="
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #34] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages com.example"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #35] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.example
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #36] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages com.example.test"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #37] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.example.test
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #38] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "rm -fr /data/local/tmp/detox"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #39] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/detox"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #40] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 push "/Users/vagrant/git/android/app/build/outputs/apk/example/release/example-release.apk" "/data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #41] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #42] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 push "/Users/vagrant/git/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/example/release/example-release-androidTest.apk" "/data/local/tmp/detox/Test.apk"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #43] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Test.apk"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #44] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "date +\"%m-%d %T.000\""
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #45] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:50966 tcp:50966
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #46] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list instrumentation"
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #47] [pid=10309] /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:50966 -e detoxSessionId 1e05 -e debug false com.example.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #48] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "ps | grep \"com\.example\.test$\""
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=1e05)
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=testee, sessionId=1e05
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=1e05
detox[9851] INFO:  Test is assigned to emulator-5554 (emulator)
detox[9851] INFO:  Test: should run the tests properly
detox[9851] INFO:  Test: should run the tests properly [FAIL]

detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 11324]: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:51297 -e detoxSessionId 1e05 -e debug false com.example.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=1e05
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 11324]: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:51297 -e detoxSessionId 1e05 -e debug false com.example.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox[9851] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #127] "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 reverse --remove tcp:51297
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=testee, sessionId=1e05
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=tester not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=1e05)
detox[9851] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
FAIL e2e/test.e2e.ts (98.619 s)
  Test
    ✕ should run the tests properly (16819 ms)
  ● Test › should run the tests properly
    Test Failed: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Root:
    Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@883a40, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@883a40, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#110 ty=1 fl=#81810900 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x10302f6 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#110 ty=1 fl=#81810900 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x10302f6 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}}
      10 |   await waitFor(element(by.id(elementId)))
      11 |     .toBeVisible()
    > 12 |     .withTimeout(timeout);
         |      ^
      13 | 
      14 | export const waitForNotVisible = async (elementId: string, timeout: number = 50000) =>
      15 |   await waitFor(element(by.id(elementId)))
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer I got from bitrise clarified this for me, turns out their system infrastructure is not built to support detox properly and this is a common issue. Also, they are working on a new infrastructure, which might (or might not) solve this issue in the future.

Edit: they have the new infrastructure now, but I haven't tried it